# after_cancel usage as a stop method

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I am trying to use after_cancel to stop an animated loop in a simple image viewer. I have read the documentation on Tcl, searched here and google, and explored the python subreddits. My error is:

```
TclError: wrong # args: should be "after cancel id|command"
```

This occurs in the last line of the following code (please don't kill me for using globals, this project is just an image viewer to display weather forecast products in our office):

```
n_images = 2
images = [PhotoImage(file="filename"+str(i)+".gif") for i in range(n_images)]
current_image = -1

def change_image():
    displayFrame.delete('Animate')
    displayFrame.create_image(0,0, anchor=NW,
                        image=images[current_image], tag='Animate')
    displayFrame.update_idletasks() #Force redraw

callback = None

def animate():
    forward()
    callback = root.after(1000, animate)

def forward():
    global current_image
    current_image += 1
    if current_image >= n_images:
        current_image = 0
    change_image()

def back():
    global current_image
    current_image -= 1
    if current_image < 0:
        current_image = n_images-1
    change_image()

def stop():
    root.after_cancel(callback)
```

If there is a more appropriate method to stop an animated loop in Tkinter, please let me know!

Comment: Where is `stop` being called?

Comment: In response to your comment on my answer to the previous version of this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27297814/tkinter-image-viewer-method/27304112?noredirect=1#comment43081483_27304112 I said that animate needs `global callback` added and edited it into my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code here is not setting a global variable, but a local variable:

```
callback = None

def animate():
    forward()
    callback = root.after(1000, animate)
```

Here, `callback` will remain set to `None`, and so your `root.after_cancel(callback)` is equivalent to `root.after_cancel(None)`, which TK doesn't like. Try changing your `animate` function to:

```
def animate():
    global callback
    forward()
    callback = root.after(1000, animate)
```

Disclaimer: I agree with Kevin, globals multiply rapidly and turn on their master, so use a class. The variables are then locked up and can't get you.

Comment: Good, I was worried there were other problems that I'd missed.

Answer (score 7):

An alternative to using `after_cancel` is, you could use an additional global value to track whether the loop ought to continue.

```
should_continue_animating = True

def animate():
    forward()
    if should_continue_animating:
        root.after(1000, animate)

def stop():
    global should_continue_animating
    should_continue_animating = False
```

---

Bonus design tip: it may be useful to make all of your functions into the methods of a single class. Then you would have `self.current_image` and `self.should_continue_animating` instead of global values. This would be a good design choice if you want to animate more than one image at once.