# TypeError: after_cancel() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am making a metronome using Tkinter and to get the ticking sound to play I am using `screen.after()`, but when I try to stop the loop so that the beats per second can be changed, I'm getting an error, `TypeError: after_cancel() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given` even though I have indeed given 2 arguments and not three.
Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from time import sleep
import os
import sys
times1 = 0
times2 = 1
def quit_():
    screen.destroy()
    sys.exit()
def run():
    global times1
    global times2
    times1 += 1
    bpm = bpm_.get()
    entry.delete(0, END)
    bpm = int(bpm)
    bpm = bpm/60
    bpm = 1/bpm
    def run_():
        global times1
        global times2
        sleep(bpm)
        os.system("afplay metronome.wav&")
        screen.after(1,run_)
        if times1 > times2:
            screen.after_cancel(1,run_)
            times1 = 0
            times2 = 1
    run_()
def main():
    global bpm_
    global entry
    bpm_ = StringVar()
    Label(screen, text="").pack()
    Label(screen, text = "enter a bpm").pack()
    entry = Entry(screen, textvariable=bpm_)
    entry.pack()
    Label(screen, text="").pack()
    Button(screen, text = "enter", command = run).pack()
    Label(screen, text="").pack()
    Button(screen, text = "quit", command = quit_).pack()
screen = Tk()
main()
screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: you forget that as a class memeber it also gets a `self` so `screen.after_cancel(1,run_)` is technically `screen.after_cancel(self, 1, run_)` which is indeed 3 parameters. I think you need to remove the `1` from the call

Comment: ***"TypeError: after_cancel() takes 2 positional"***: It will not work at all, you need the `after id` you get from: `aid = screen.after(...`. Read [Widget.after_cancel-method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after_cancel-method)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [after\_cancel usage as a stop method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27319580/after-cancel-usage-as-a-stop-method)

Comment: The second comment to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27319580/after-cancel-usage-as-a-stop-method helped, Thanks!