# Short animation from one image to another

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

Given two images with the same size, I'm trying to transform one into another, but with several frames in between them.

My idea of workflow is something like:

retrieve pixel matrix from images:

```
img1_pixels = img1.load()
img2_pixels = img2.load()
```

and create a frame like:

```
for y in range(11):
    x = 10 - y
    frame = (x*0.1)*img1_pixels + (y*0.1)*img2_pixels
    frame.show()
    time.sleep(1)
```

I've read some stuff and I know is recommended to use **tkinter** instead of **pil** since `show()` is just for debugging.

The problem is that I can't find an example in which tkinter and pil are used to display a set of frames in order to generate an animation.

I can make it work if I bind the update to a keystroke. At the moment I use `time.sleep` the script freezes.

Does anyone have an example or a suggestion of a good way to do it?

Thank you,
Lucas.

Comment: Have you tried using `after` method ?

Comment: There are many examples of animation on this site. For example, does the following link help? http://stackoverflow.com/q/27297814/7432

Comment: @StevoMitric Thank you! I've managed to call the function as I wanted with the `after` function.